# How to make a function that receives an integer and returns only its odd digits?

Tags: python

```
def odd_numbers(x):
    res = 0
    dig = 0
    while x > 0:
        dig = x % 10
        if dig % 2 != 0:
            ___________________
        x = x // 10
    return(res)
```

Example:

Input: `345321`

Output: `3531`

I was doing something like this, analyze each digit but I'm having trouble in putting them in my return. I'm new to python and I'm just learning, I know for cycles but I'd like to try and get this one done with a while, however I'd also be happy with an answer using for cycle.

Comment: Do you need to return an integer or is a list okay? Even if you have to return an integer, you can add the numbers to a list first and then build the integer from the list. Also [edit] your question to includeexample inputs and outputs

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I believe I can't use lists because this a problem from an exercises sheet and this is from the first module in which we still haven't learned lists

Comment: `3531` are odd numbers, not even numbers.

Comment: @khelwood oh I'm sorry, my bad. I'm not fluent in english. So yes, the function returns and integer with only its odd numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in the other direction

```
def even_numbers(x):
    res = 0
    fac = 1
    while x > 0:
        dig = x % 10
        if dig % 2 != 0:
            res += dig * fac
            fac *= 10
        x //= 10
    return res
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that in inverts the digits' order. I was trying to avoid that, without using lists aswel.

Comment: `if dig % 2 != 0:` is equivalent to `if dig % 2:`  why are you putting the `!=0` part?

Comment: @vugod Fixed it.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I copied it from question.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it! Thank you so much!!
@SembeiNorimaki I put that, I'm a newbie I believe he tried to simple it down for me

Comment: @vugod There was a bug in my previous version. I fixed it. The line `x //= 10` has to be outside the if condition.

Comment: `if dig % 2:` is not easily comprehensible. People may read it as "if dig is divisible by two".